# NSArray coming as null while object has value

Tags: ios, objective-c

The following code is driving me crazy:

```
-(void)fetchEventDetails
{    
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domain.com/ios/read.php"]];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];


    for(id object in dict){
    //NSLog(@"city : %@",object[@"city"]);
//        NSLog(@"title : %@",object[@"title"]);
//        NSLog(@"description : %@",object[@"description"]);
        [_eventsTitles addObject:object[@"title"]];
        [_eventsCity addObject:object[@"city"]];
    }


    NSLog(@"Array : %@", _eventsCity);
}
```

So if I uncomment the first line of the for loop, it prints all the cities. if I print the NSArray, it shows null. Both defined in .h file the same way, i.e. eventsTitles and eventsCity. What could be wrong?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You never created eventsCity.

Comment: may be you did not initialize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you defining `_eventsTitles` and `_eventsCity` elsewhere?

Try this:

```
-(void)fetchEventDetails
{    
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domain.com/ios/read.php"]];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    _eventsTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _eventsCity = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(id object in dict){
    //NSLog(@"city : %@",object[@"city"]);
//        NSLog(@"title : %@",object[@"title"]);
//        NSLog(@"description : %@",object[@"description"]);
        [_eventsTitles addObject:object[@"title"]];
        [_eventsCity addObject:object[@"city"]];
    }


    NSLog(@"Array : %@", _eventsCity);
}
```

Comment: They are defined in the header files. The eventTitles is working fine. only city is not

Comment: @sys_debug - "defined" is not "created".

Comment: Im not asking if they were defined, I'm asking if they were allocated and initialized.

Comment: You could put it in the `init` function of your class, or if this is a View Controller, in the `viewDidLoad` function.

Comment: @sys_debug - You should learn the difference between an object and a pointer to an object.  Nothing special for Objective-C, other than the syntax is a bit screwy.

Comment: done. It is working now. Yes it is screwy so much! I am used to clean java.

Comment: In "clean java" you would have crashed with a NullPointerException. ObjC "helps" you by allowing you to use nil object pointers, and all of its methods return a zero type of value (depending on its type) in this case.

Answer (score 0):

did you initialize `self.eventsCity` and `self.eventsTitles` as empty `NSMutableArray`s? Simply declaring them as `@properties` leaves them as `nil.

You should also probably reference them not as instance variables, but as `self.arrayName`. You can do lazy instantiation that way as well so you don't have this problem =)

EDIT: Adding lazy instantiation code so you have an example of what I meant:

```
- (NSMutableArray)eventsCity
{
    if (_eventsCity == nil)
       _eventsCity = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _eventsCity;
}
```

Using this, it will create an empty array for you if you haven't made one yet any time you reference `self.eventsCity`